# "Amazed by how" vs "amazed how"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> I am amazed by how friendly these people are.
>
> I'm amazed how friendly these people are.

What is the difference between the usage with *by* and the usage without?

Comment: No difference in meaning, IMHO. The first is more grammatically correct, but eliding the preposition is common in informal conversation.

Comment: See a similar question about "for" a couple hours later: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216985/using-for-when-talking-about-continuous-actions

Comment: A more common UK English usage would be: I am amazed at how friendly...

Comment: Why the downvote?  (And the 'for' question is likely not showing the same effect.)

Comment: "amazed at how" also common in AmE, but AFAIK no more common than "amazed by how" or "amazed how"